# Webpages redirects to index.php after ssl installation

Tags: ssl, redirect

I have installed ssl certificates in all the websites. It was a long and hectic process with redirects and all those stuff.
The websites `//domain.com/about.html` still appears in google search and is not yet redirected to https version. I guess it might take some time. But the websites `//domain.com/about.html` when clicked gets redirect to `//domain.com/index.php`  All the other urls are redirected to `/index.php`.  What can be the issue? Below is the code of `.htaccess` file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress


RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainn.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```